# Is this the correct use of commas in a list?

Tags: grammar, commas, lists

```
This is a teacher-run, flexible, inclusive, event.
```

OR

```
This is a teacher-run, flexible, inclusive event.
```

Which of these should I be using and what is the grammatical reason for this? Thank you!

Comment: A list comma acts as a conjunction: replace each comma by "and" and see what happens...

Comment: It depends on what's intended. In theory, they could both be grammatical. The first sentence would be grammatical if *inclusive* is nonrestrictive. However, that would be a highly unlikely interpretation of intent. You can reverse the sentences for easier analysis. 1. *This is an event that is teacher-run and flexible (inclusive).* 2. *This is an event that is teacher-run, flexible, and inclusive.*